# Error: The maxLength facet is not applicable to types derived from xs:integer

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

When I try

```
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">
        <xsd:maxLength value="35"/>
        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I get the error

> The `maxLength` facet is not applicable to types derived from `xs:integer`

How can I achieve a positive integer with `minLength` and `maxLength`?

Comment: Are you looking for a number between 1 and 35, or are you looking for a number with between 1 and 35 digits?  Inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: sorry, for the confusion: a number with between 1 and 35 digits included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow integers between 1..35, inclusive:

```
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="35"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

To allow integers with 1..35 digits:

```
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">
        <xsd:pattern value="\d{1,35}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```